# Run excel formula through VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to VLOOKUP some value in 2 sheets and if the value is found then i am putting a hyperlink on the Sheet 1 cell to point it to the Sheet 2 cell.

I have written an Excel formula for the same and it is working fine. But I am unable to convert it into a VBA formula. What am I doing wrong?

Excel formula:
    `=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[7],Sheet2!R1C1:R20C1,1,FALSE)),RC[7],HYPERLINK(CELL("address",INDEX(Sheet2!R1C1:R20C1,MATCH(RC[7],Sheet2!R1C1:R20C1,0))),RC[7]))`

VBA formula which i have tried:

```
Sheets(4).Formula = "= IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[7],Sheet2!R4C2:R" & Lrow2 & "C2,1,FALSE)),RC[7],HYPERLINK(CELL(" & """address""" & ",INDEX(Sheet2!R4C2:" & "R" & Lrow2 & "C2,MATCH(RC[7],Sheet2!R4C2:" & "R" & Lrow2 & "C2,0))),RC[7]))"
```

P.S.: Do not worry about the row and column indexes. I wrote the formula for test file and writing the vba for the master file.

Comment: Do consider "going back to basics". What do you want to achieve here? Your excel formula and supporting vba is *extremely* brittle.

Comment: Just tryied your VBA formula, with added `Cells(1,1)` and it worked. Note I changed the worksheet index to 1, for test purposes. `Sheets(1).Cells(1,1).Formula = _
"=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[7],Sheet2!R4C2:R" & Lrow2 & "C2,1,FALSE)),RC[7],HYPERLINK(CELL(" & """address""" & ",INDEX(Sheet2!R4C2:" & "R" & Lrow2 & "C2,MATCH(RC[7],Sheet2!R4C2:" & "R" & Lrow2 & "C2,0))),RC[7]))"`

Comment: @BranislavKollár Thanks. The formula is now working.     'Sheets(1).Cells(Lrow3, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "= IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet4!R" & Lrow3 & "C9,Sheet2!R4C2:R" & Lrow2 & "C2,1,FALSE)),Sheet4!R" & Lrow3 & "C9,HYPERLINK(CELL(" & """address""" & ",INDEX(Sheet2!R4C2:" & "R" & Lrow2 & "C2,MATCH(Sheet4!R" & Lrow3 & "C9,Sheet2!R4C2:" & "R" & Lrow2 & "C2,0))),Sheet4!R" & Lrow3 & "C9))" '  But i got struck with another problem. When i am running my entire code,  a popup is being displayed 2 times (1 for Sheet4 and the other for Sheet2) asking for File names. Is anything wrong with the """address"""?

Comment: I don't know mate. Try updating the quesiton with this new issue. It will be more visible to other SE users, more likely to get answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a minor mistake you've done.

`Sheets(4).Formula = ""`  represents the formula applied on sheet4.Logically sheet 4 has almost million rows. Where will the formula sit?

```
Sheet(4).cells(row, column).Formula = ""
```

Here is one example i have just wrote few min back for sumif

```
  shPivotAdjustmentsIRSPV.Cells(NumRows, NumColumns + 1).Formula =
 "=Sum(" & shPivotAdjustmentsIRSPV.Cells(3, NumColumns + 1).Address &
 ":" & shPivotAdjustmentsIRSPV.Cells(NumRows - 2, NumColumns +
 1).Address & ")"
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, but i am still getting the run-time error. Here is what i have tried:                                                                      For Rows1 = 6 To Lrow1
Sheets(4).Cells(Rows1, 3).Formula = "= IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[7],Sheet2!R4C2:R" & Lrow2 & "C2,1,FALSE)),RC[7],HYPERLINK(CELL(" & """address""" & ",INDEX(Sheet2!R4C2:" & "R" & Lrow2 & "C2,MATCH(RC[7],Sheet2!R4C2:" & "R" & Lrow2 & "C2,0))),RC[7]))"
Next Rows1

Comment: Yeah.Please try using .FormulaR1C1 if you specify rows & columns.Adding to it, I could find one mistake in above code `code` Sheets(4).Cells(Rows1, 3).Formula  where tag **bold** Rows1 is invalid. Just use `code`  Sheets(4).Cells(1, 3). To verify, Can you see the formula appearing in row1,column 3 , after the code is executed.

Comment: @MohitBagadia pleasure dude. Someone might help me when i have queries. May be you too!!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to a range, you need to use the `.FormulaR1C1` property if you are going to use R1C1 references:

```
Sheets(4).Range("A7").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[7],Sheet2!R4C2:R" & Lrow2 & "C2,1,FALSE)),RC[7],HYPERLINK(CELL(""address"",INDEX(Sheet2!R4C2:R" & Lrow2 & "C2,MATCH(RC[7],Sheet2!R4C2:R" & Lrow2 & "C2,0))),RC[7]))"
```